# Display-only Column Formatting in Vim for Character-Separated Value Files

Tags: vim, csv

I would like to be able to nondestructively align columns when I am editing csv files in vim.

I know of various ways to tabularize/align columned data in vim, but they all modify the file itself rather than the view of the file. I have started using the csv.vim plugin which is quite nice and it would be great if I could integrate a solution into its workflow, since it already automatically detects and highlights columns accordingly.

Ideally the display spacing would not be considered characters so movement commands would behave as if they weren't there.

Answer (score 2):

That unfortunately isn't possible, and it doesn't fit well into Vim's mission of a powerful *text* (in contrast to WYSIWYG) editor.

The closest available functionality in Vim is the (recent) *conceal* feature, which works the other way around: It can (though with weaknesses) condense multiple characters into a single (or none) character cell representation. You'd need the opposite: expanding a single whitespace into a variable number of display cells. There once was talk about a "variable tabstops" patch on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php), but that has gotten nowhere.

The best workaround available is in the mentioned *csv.vim* plugin, which (through `:[Un]ArrangeColumn`) can (temporarily) modify the text itself (also automatically on open/save; cp. `:help csv-arrange-autocmd`.

Comment: I figured the only way possible might be to modify the file on open/write but I was hoping there would be something more elegant. I don't see how it doesn't fit into the vim way and it certainly doesn't seem like a WYSIWYG feature. I suppose automatic alignment on open/write combined with automatic remapping of movement commands to ignore multiple spaces might be satisfactory.